# Convert Jquery Plugin into Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having problem when converting my jquery plugin into angular directives, here's my jquery plugin call:

```
$('#fixed_hdr2').fxdHdrCol({
        fixedCols: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: 400,
        colModal: [
        { width: 50, align: 'center' },
        { width: 110, align: 'center' },
        { width: 170, align: 'left' },
        { width: 250, align: 'left' },
        { width: 100, align: 'left' },
        { width: 70, align: 'left' },
        { width: 100, align: 'left' },
        { width: 100, align: 'center' },
        { width: 90, align: 'left' },
        { width: 400, align: 'left' }
        ],
        sort: true
    });
```

And when I convert it into angular directives it will look like this:

```
myApp.directive('fixedTable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.fxdHdrCol({
            fixedCols: attrs.fixedCols,
            width: attrs.width,
            height: attrs.height,
            colModal: [
               { width: 80, align: 'left'},
               { width: 250, align: 'left'},
               { width: 100, align: 'left'},
               { width: 100, align: 'left'},
               { width: 130, align: 'left'},
               { width: 100, align: 'left'},
               { width: 150, align: 'left'},
               { width: 130, align: 'center'},
               { width: 100, align: 'left'},
               { width: 150, align: 'left'}
            ]
        });
    }
}; })
```

here's my error -> **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined"**
I know I have mistake in converting but I don't know how to convert it correctly. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something is trying to get `width` off of an object that is undefined. Is the error occurring inside the plugin?

Comment: yeah I already added it, <table fixed-table fixed-cols="3" height="300" width="100%"> I think my problem is in the colModal. I don't know how to convert this and call it in my element.

Comment: attr values will likely be string, test typeof to be sure. Also is jquery included before anugular library?

Comment: @charlietfl how? sorry but please give me example. Thanks

Comment: Did you try console.log(attrs)? what is inside attrs?

Comment: @axel.michel here->   {$$element: e.fn.init[1], $attr: Object, fixedTable: "", fixedCols: "3", height: "300"…}

Comment: here's the link of what I want to use http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/ if you know how to convert this into angular please help.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

your html code?

**Error:**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined"

Possibility 1：width: attrs.width
Possibility 2：colModal and table's column are Inconsistent